# 14.04 GT940M nVidia X Server Setting is null

Tags: 14.04, nvidia-settings, nvidia-geforce

My computer has an nVidia GT940M graphics card, and I've installed the nVidia 352.79 driver. The nVidia X server settings configuration panel does not display all of the settings. How can I fix it?
Please help me.

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

Comment: You could try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics/760935#760935

Comment: I reinstall ubuntu and try this referer link belows. Buut Nvidia Corporation: Unknown. X server setting is same as old.

Comment: @Üzeyir G. You should disable secure boot if you have it. When computer boots select "Change secure boot state" and enter the password characters it wants. I had the same problem now I have all the settings.

Comment: @razorx. Very thanks for advice. Now all i have all settings. Only "Addtional Driver" tabs "Nvidia Corparation: Unknown". Did you have this problem?